# How to trim characters of excel column before uploading to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading an excel file to my database. I have an `INVOICE` column in the excel sheet. I want to store only the first 10 digits of that column into the database.

For example:

**Excel file**
*Invoice*
`123354647478483`

I want to trim this number and store only the first 10 digits in the database like `1233546474`.

```
string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] {    
    new DataColumn("Invoice#", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("P#O##", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Line#", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Invoice Date",typeof(DateTime)),
    new DataColumn("Gross", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Disc", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("NET", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Date Pd", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Check#/Doc#", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Additional Info", typeof(string))
});

using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
{
    oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
}
excel_con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query `"SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"`

to

`"SELECT LEFT(Invoice#, 10) as NewInvoice, * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"`

and change `new DataColumn("Invoice#", typeof(string)),`

to

`new DataColumn("NewInvoice", typeof(string)),`

Edit: maybe you would need to mention all the required columns in the `Select` statement when doing this.

While using column names in `Select` statement use `[` & `]` for column names with **spaces** and **special characters**. Thus query will look like:

`SELECT Left([Invoice#], 10) as NewInvoice, [P#O##],[Line#],[Invoice Date],Gross,Disc,NET,[Date Pd],[Check#/Doc#],[Additional Info] FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"`

Comment: Its giving me a syntax error in date in query expression 'LEFT(Invoice# , 10)'.

Comment: uh oh :/ Isn't `Invoice` the column having _Invoice Number_?

Comment: First temme this, does the above method works without trimming, i mean does the `dtExcelData` table gets filled with excel data

Comment: Yes it does. i fill the data into dtExcelData first then do a bulk insert onto the sql table. But now i need to trim the invoice column

Comment: try the query like this `"SELECT LEFT(Invoice, 10) as NewInvoice, *add rest of the columns  you need(comma separated) * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"` then tell the result

Comment: `SELECT Left(Invoice#, 10)as NewInvoice, P#O##,Line#,Invoice Date,Gross,Disc,NET,Date Pd,Check#/Doc#,Additional Info FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"`

Comment: Syntax error in date in query expression 'Left(Invoice#, 10)'.

Comment: This is happening because `Invoice Date` column has space in-between, so use it like this `SELECT Left([Invoice#], 10) as NewInvoice, [P#O##],[Line#],[Invoice Date],Gross,Disc,NET,[Date Pd],[Check#/Doc#],[Additional Info] FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"`. Square brackets are used when a column name contains space or special characters